# Filipino with multiple work visa - immigration check

Tags: philippines, philippine-citizens

I am a Filipino citizen and have a valid work visa and POEA records ([OEC](https://www.philippine-embassy.org.sg/labor/household-service-workers/registration-oec-issuance/)) working in Malaysia. If I were to transfer to another country and get work visa in that country, will I have any trouble if I go home to the Philippines while still have work visa in Malaysia?

**Scenario**

My work permit in Malaysia is valid until February 2020, and I am planning to go home to the Philippines for Christmas. But I already received my work visa for Hong Kong and will start on April 2020. If I go home on December and come back to Malaysia on January 5, 2020, I would still have a valid work visa for Malaysia and an OEC reflecting that, but no OEC for Hong Kong.

What if the immigration officer in Manila sees that I have a future-dated work visa for Hong Kong? Will they stop me? If I tell them that I will apply for an OEC once I get to Hong Kong, would that be enough?

Answer (score 1):

From the [How to Apply for Overseas Employment Cetificate (OEC) in Hong Kong](https://hongkongofw.com/overseas-employment-certificate-oec/) site states:

> When Filipino domestic helpers go back home for the holidays, they need to obtain an Overseas Employment Certificate (OEC) or an “Exit Permit” first so that they will be allowed to **re-enter Hong Kong** from the Philippines. The OEC is one of the requirements needed for every re-entry from the Philippines, including home leave.
>   ...
>   **Important**: OECs are valid only for a single exit from the Philippines.

This implys that a OEC from Hong Kong must be applied for **after** you have started working in Hong Kong.

When you leave the Philippines after Christmas **going back to** Malaysia (with a OEC for Malaysia) you will have the needed  “Exit Permit” for that trip.

Immigration should not be interested in the Hong Kong Visa that **starts in April 2020**.